# convert form hex buffer to int using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a hex buffer in Node js like this:

```
buffer <00 E0>
```

I need to convert to int using little endianess. So I would read E0 00 -> 57344

For the moment I use this method:

```
var str = "0x" + buffer [i] .toString ('16 '). toString + buffer [i-1] .toString ('16'). toString to convert to string
```

var result = parseInt (str).

This method works but sometimes I get errors like this: buffer [0] = 00 but I receve 0 instead 00 or 1 instead to 01 or 10,

Is there another way to get this convertons or to solve this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the [Buffer.readInt*LE or Buffer.readUInt*LE](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) methods (the * stands for the integer size, LE for little endian). Taking your code as an example, you can use [Buffer.readIntLE](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_readintle_offset_bytelength):

```
Buffer.from([ 0x00, 0xe0]).readUIntLE(0, 2)
```

If you have a variable buffer size:

```
var buffer = Buffer.from(bytes);
var result = buffer.readUIntLE(0, bytes.length) // assumes bytes.length is even
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this method and its work, but reading doc:" Reads byteLength number of bytes from buf at the specified offset and interprets the result as an unsigned, little-endian integer supporting up to 48 bits of accuracy." When I have a want read a number of byte < 6 its works but when I need to convert a number of bytes > 6 (128 forx example) doesn't work. How can I convert it? Thanks

Comment: You asked about working with an integer, so I assumed 32 bits. You can read a 64 bits buffer by using `readBigInt64LE` instead. More than that is not an integer anymore, so you'd need a more involved code.

Comment: Yes! In this cases I must convert to String. I read and covert to Integer before (using readUIntLE) and then I use fromCharCode(int) to get a String. Thanks!!